# Xcode 8: Your account does not have sufficient permissions to modify containers

Tags: xcode

I'm getting this error with code signing with Xcode 8:

> Your account does not have sufficient permissions to modify containers

[image]

What does it want from me?

Comment: Answers mentioning 'admin' might have the right solution if the accepted answer doesn't work for you. They saved me!

Comment: I had this problem and as the error says, my account really didn't have enough permissions. So I asked another guy to edit Bundle Id and enable the container in https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list

Answer (score 96):

I also faced this issue in XCode 8.3.3 (8E3004b). I just went to *Project Settings* → *Capabilities* tab, then toggled iCloud off and on. Once I went back to the *General* tab, the errors were gone.

Comment: Thanks for this one , spent couple hours trying to fix it

Comment: This is the solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: worked for me on xCode 9.2, please include this in your anser.

Thanks

Comment: Even though this fixed. Can anyone please tell why does it happen?

Comment: Seems like it's still a thing in XCode 11. Toggle each of the containers within the iCloud section under Signing & Capabilities

Comment: The same strange behaviour in XCode 11.0

Comment: yep, still a thing in XCode 11.0

Comment: For me I just unchecked an Apple Pay entitlement's merchant ID.

Comment: Same for Xcode 12...

Answer (score 6):

This seems like it may be a bug with XCode 8.
To resolve this, I unchecked the "automatically manage signing" checkbox in the of my target's General settings. I then archived my project by manually setting the provisioning profiles. After that succeeded, I went back and again checked the "automatically manage signing" checkbox and it stopped complaining with errors that made no sense.

Comment: i had to do what you suggested and Restart XCode before re-enabling Auto Signing

Answer (score 3):

Just had this issue with XCode 8.3.2 after we enabled iCloud Capabilities and the entitlements changed. We use automatic signing - xcode managed profile. Going into Xcode -> Preferences -> Download All Profiles wouldn't fix the problem UNTIL we temporarily made team members Admin and repeated the process. At that point XCode realized the new provisioning profile and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

Just goto Xcode capabilities section and see if any of the capability showing error then disable that and enable again. Then come to your Signing section in General. The issues will go now

Answer (score 3):

1) Remove all automatically created provision profiles from

```
~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/
```

2) In Xcode 11.1 and higher remove and add capabilities

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue in XCODE Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b). To resolve this go to project settings. In capabilities tab -> iCloud -> containers. Verify whether valid iCloud containers are selected and you have permission to access these containers. This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem too after I added a new device with Xcode 8.3.3 (same issue present in Xcode beta 9.0 as well). My Apple Developer account wasn't an administrator at the time either. I tried deleting my provisioning profiles and re-downloading them but that didn't work. I tried manually downloading and installing the provisioning profiles from developer.apple.com, but that didn't work either. I had my Apple Developer account made an Administrator following advice from dchappelle `https://stackoverflow.com/a/43812123/5760384` and voila! The provisioning errors went away. (I'd reply to his post, but I don't have enough reputation.)

Full text of error:

> Your account does not have sufficient permissions to modify
>   containers. Provisioning profile "myApp" doesn't include the currently
>   selected device "myDevice". Code signing is required for product type
>   'Application' in SDK 10.3

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution, depending on your needs, is to upgrade to the paid version of the Apple Developer Program; this gives you access to the iCloud container features. Once paid and activated (the membership application takes a few hours to go through if you're an individual... sometimes a few days if you're a business) you'll need to enable iCloud features via the online dashboard or via XCode as per Apple's instructions. You may then have to restart XCode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Xcode 9.2. But in my case, the problem was in **Keychain**: my dev certificate was saved into *login* keychain by default. I was able to build an app on a device only when I moved it to *System* keychain.

So the steps are next:

1. Open *Keychain Access*
2. Open *login* keychain (you can see the list of all keychains on the left top corner of the window)
3. Drag and drop your dev/distribution certificate into *System* keychain
4. You may need to input password.

PS: while doing this steps you also may need to unlock locks on the keychains.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I fixed it by logging in to the iTunes development portal and accepted the new Terms & Conditions.  I was basically locked out until these were accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because I was in *another* team (my university team account), which was **severely limiting my access** to `developer.apple.com` features. **Once I left that team** (I added an answers [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345313/how-to-leave-apple-developer-program-on-developer-apple-com) because even this was a bit of a pain), I was able to remove & re-add my account to XCode. It then worked.

EDIT: It happened again on a new machine (an M1 mac), and this time I had left the university account. **By removing and adding back "Apple Pay" capability in `Signing & Capabilities`, it immediately fixed itself.**

---

None of the other answers worked for me. E.g. The app doesn't even use iCloud, and enabling-disabling it didn't help. Deleting profiles, revoking certificates, disabling/re-enabling automatically manage signing also didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Xcode -> preferences -> Accounts.
Remove your Apple ID & login back. Refresh the signing in on your project target

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue using Xcode 9.3
Solution:

```
1 - Deselect "Automatic manage signing"
2 - Created a Provisioning profile for dev and dist and added in Keychain.
3 - Again when you come back to Sighing (debug and release) you can see your created provisioning profile in a dropdown 
4 - Crate archive by selecting "Generic iOS devices" in the project schema
```